# How do I bind an event to a popup window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I seem to be unable to bind an event to a popup window. What's the correct way of doing this? I know you have to pass the window you'd like to bind the event to but I can't seem to find any info on this *anywhere*--have been searching for the past hour on information but I don't even have a single link to show for my efforts. Here are a few of my various attempts:

```
// the popup window is referenced by "display.window"
// #map is a <canvas> element occupying 100% of the new window

// I'll just try passing in the context first...
$(display.window, "#map").keydown(function(e) {
    // do stuff
});

// maybe the other way around?
$("#map", display.window).keydown(function(e) {
    // do stuff
});

// what if I just try to add the event right to the window?
$(display.window).keydown(function(e) {
    // do stuff
});

// nope, maybe bind will do the trick
$(display.window).bind(function(e) {
    // do stuff
});

// maybe the new window's DOM isn't loaded yet?
$(display.window).ready(function() {
    $(this).keypress(function(e) {
        // do stuff
    });
});
```

None of these worked. What am I missing?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/zWJ5d/ (beware the popup blocker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to do this inside the code you are using to create the popup, it would be nice to see that part of the code.

Also, the currently recommended way to subscribe to an event is using the `.on()` jQuery method.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(display.window).on('keydown', function(e) {
    //Good stuff here
});
```

Totally untested, hope this helps you down the right path.

---

Another thing that has occurred to me, do you really need a popup? That's asking for trouble from popup blockers and the like... You may be better off implementing a nice modal window solution, then your "window" would be a part of the same DOM, and that should make creating the event listener trivial.

jQuery UI has a nice "dialog" widget

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Using `.on()` and (incidentally) upgrading to the latest version of jQuery did the trick. Thanks! (I'm on a tight schedule so this is really helpful) Will accept in 1 minute.